# Code to run recursive feature extraction multiple iteration each time deleating the lowest ranked feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, rfe

Ok so I want to run recursive feature extraction on my dataset with X amount of features and at each iteration remove the lowest ranked feature than re-run the RFE until I am only left with 5 features. However, I have no idea how to code this.

The first part of running the RFE is fine but I don't want to sit and manually rerun the RFE and remove one feature at a time it will take forever to do so. Could somebody help me code this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=2000, n_features=85, random_state=42)


# split data into train and test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# if we need train test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

estimator = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, min_samples_leaf=5,
                             min_samples_split=8, max_features='auto',
                             max_depth=90, bootstrap=True)
selector = RFE(estimator, 83, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X_train, y_train)


# predict and get rankings and optimal number of features
selector.fit(X_test, y_test)
selector.predict(X_test)
ranking = selector.ranking_
y_hats = selector.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_hats]
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Test Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy*100.0))


# index rankings
header = X_test.columns
frame = pd.DataFrame(ranking, index=header)
frame = frame.rename(columns = {frame.columns[0]: 'rankings'}, inplace = False)
frame = frame.sort_values(by = 'rankings', ascending=True)

# save table
from pandas.tools.plotting import table
ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=True) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table(ax, frame)  # where df is your data frame
```

Answer (score 0):

```
features = [1, 28, 9, 17, 0, 16, 9]

def recursive(features, max_features=5, max_iterations=100):
    feature_length = len(features)
    long_enough = (feature_length <= max_features)
    tried_too_many_times = (max_iterations < 1)
    if long_enough or tried_too_many_times:
        raise GeneratorExit(
            {
                'features': features,
                'iterations': max_iterations,
            }
        )
    _features = sorted(features, reverse=True)
    lowest = _features.pop()
    print('Removing', lowest)
    max_iterations -= 1
    yield from recursive(_features, max_features=max_features, max_iterations=max_iterations)


s = recursive(features)

try:
    list(s)
except GeneratorExit as e:
    context = e.args[0]

# Removing 0
# Removing 1

context
# {'features': [28, 17, 16, 9, 9], 'iterations': 98}
```

Comment: Ok, first thank you, I don't know if this works yet will have to sit down tomorrow and try to make it work & understand it. Second, how do I learn to come up with this stuff on my own?? I feel like these stupid online python courses aren't really teaching me this kind of stuff...

Comment: Could you explain and expand on your answer a bit cause I'm not understanding how to implement this in my code.

Comment: You learn to come up with better than this stuff as you solve real world problems. The online python courses feel stupid for not teaching you this kind of stuff simply because they're not. As you grapple with real problems to which you often do not find the solution online, you come up with your own. And then you use that as the basis for other problems.

For example, I had to write for an system of hundreds of equationsentered as text by users. To do that, I had to recursively go through the equations and update the system. The code I shared is inspired by that. It's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by very simply just doing this:

```
iters = list(range(1, 235))
iters = iters[::-1]

for i in iters:


    estimator = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, min_samples_leaf=5,
                             min_samples_split=8, max_features='auto',
                             max_depth=90, bootstrap=True)
    selector = RFE(estimator, i, step=1)
    selector = selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
```